# Issue with mysql multiple left join and group by

Tags: mysql

Well i got 3 tables:

**tb1:**

```
tb1_id PK
tb1_name
```

**tb2:**

```
tb2_id PK
tb1_id FK
```

**tb3:**

```
tb3_id PK
tb2_id FK
```

and i got this query:

```
select a.tb1_nome
      ,b.tb2_id
      ,count(c.tb2_id) as lins 
 from tb1 a 
      left join tb2 b on a.tb1_id=b.tb1_id 
      left join tb3 c on b.tb2_id=c.tb2_id 
 group by b.tb2_id order by a.tb1_id desc
```

but it doesn't returns all rows of tb1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i got 3 tables i need to **get all rows of tb2 that matches with tb1** and
>   show the **count of all rows of tb3 that matches with tb2**

I think that you only need to use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. `INNER JOIN` selects rows that has records on the table joined. Give this a try and have a feed back later :)

```
SELECT  a.tb1_name,
        b.tb2_id,
        COUNT(c.tb2_id) TotalCount
FROM    tb1 a 
          INNER JOIN tb2 b
             on a.tb1_id = b.tb1_id
          INNER JOIN tb3 c
             on b.tb2_id = c.tb2_id
GROUP BY a.tb1_name, b.tb2_id
ORDER BY a.tb2_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
left join tb2 b on a.tb1_id=b.tb1_id
```

maybe you have a typo because b has tb2_id only... no tb1_id

Also, if you need to get ALL tb1 rows even with no matching result on tb2, consider using outer join.